# Disable comboBox if value is null and contains selected value

Tags: javafx, lambda, java-8, combobox

I have two comboBox example comboBox a and b. I want to disable comboBox b when comboBox an is null and when selected specific value from comboBox a.

```
comboboxb.disableProperty().bind(
        JavaFxObserver.toBinding(
        JavaFxObservable.nullableValuesOf(comboboxa.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty())
            .map(test -> !comboboxaEnum.isPresent() || comboboxaEnum.equals(comboboxaEnum.XX) ))
    );
```

It is only disable when comboBox is null.

Comment: How can we select a specific value for ComboBox `a` when it is null? It is not clear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to disable the combobox using Easybind

```
 comboboxb.disableProperty()
    .bind(EasyBind.map(comboboxa.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty(),
        comboboxaEnum ->
            comboBoxAEnum == comboBoxAEnum.XX || comboBoxAEnum == null));
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need to check two conditions, then use `Bindings` logic operations:

```
comboBoxB.disableProperty().bind(
    Bindings.or(
       Bindings.equal(comboBoxA.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty(), "Value Which Disables"),
       Bindings.isNull(comboBoxA.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty())
));
```